# Django 1.6 Formset's bug: "referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to declare a formset:

```
def linkurl(request):
  UrlFormSet = formset_factory(UrlForm)
  if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = UrlFormSet(data=request.POST, instance=Link())
    if formset.is_valid():
      formset.instance.user = request.user
      formset.save()
      return redirect('home')
    else:
      formset = UrlFormSet()
  user_links_count = Link.objects.filter(user=request.user).count()
  return render_to_response(request, "addurl.html", {'formset': formset, 'linkscount': user_links_count})
```

But it always printed me : local variable 'formset' referenced before assignment. I don't know what's the issue, can someone please help me? Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

You have wrong indented `else` block, move it one step left:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = UrlFormSet(data=request.POST, instance=Link())
    # code
else: # this else block in your code should be moved left
    formset = UrlFormSet()
```